# All possible combinations between two arrays in given possitions (PYTHON)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, for example:

```
array1 = [A, B, C]
array2 = [a, b, c]
```

I want to create a matrix which contain all the possible combinations between these two arrays in the following way **with python code**:

```
[[A, B, C]
 [A, B, c]
 [A, b, C]
 [A, b, c]
 [a, B, C]
 [a, B, c]
 [a, b, C]
 [a, b, C]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
array1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

from itertools import product
out = list(product(*zip(array1, array2)))
```

output:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C'),
 ('A', 'B', 'c'),
 ('A', 'b', 'C'),
 ('A', 'b', 'c'),
 ('a', 'B', 'C'),
 ('a', 'B', 'c'),
 ('a', 'b', 'C'),
 ('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

###### as list of list

*NB. The above list of tuples should be preferred unless there is a need to **modify** the elements*

```
from itertools import product
out = list(map(list,product(*zip(array1, array2))))
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['A', 'B', 'c'],
 ['A', 'b', 'C'],
 ['A', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'B', 'C'],
 ['a', 'B', 'c'],
 ['a', 'b', 'C'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: This solution do not print a matrix 8x3 but an array 8x1 and I think there isi no way to pick only the (for example) 'A' variable of the matrix.

Comment: @Vaggelis well, you're wrong ;) In any case this is not a matrix/array but a list of list, or a list of tuples. This makes no difference unless you want to modify the values. You can easily get a list of list (`list(map(list,product(*zip(array1, array2))))`) but this is really not necessary if you don't need to alter it. You can slice in any case like a "matrix": `out[0][0]`

Comment: NB. This solution is the most efficient as it doesn't require to use `append`

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively generate all possible combinations.

```py
array1 = ['A','B','C']
array2 = ['a','b','c']
ans = []
def f(x, i):
    if i == max(len(array1), len(array2)):
        ans.append(x)
    else:
        try:
            f(x + [array1[i]], i + 1)
        except IndexError:
            pass
        try:
            f(x + [array2[i]], i + 1)
        except IndexError:
            pass

f([], 0)
print(ans)
```

**Note:** This solution also works for arrays of different length. Like `[A, B, C]` and `[a, b, c, d]`.

Comment: This does not give a matrix but a number (18 particularly)

Comment: I edited my answer. See it again, please.

Comment: Now it gives a matrix but a wrong one since it produce more than 8 combinations. For example combination: ('A', 'C', 'a') is wrong because the letter C is in the second position and i want C and c to belong only to the third position. Similarly A and a only to the fisrt position and B and b only to the second.

Comment: I missunderstood your question. I edited my answer again. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 array1=['A','B','C']
 array2=['a','b','c']
 array1.extend(array2) 
 allp = list()
 for x in array1:
      for y in array1:
           for z in array1:
                allp.append(x+y+z)
```

Comment: This don't print the solution which I am refferd to the question.